# Get the index ,while inserting a element into php numeric index array

Tags: php, arrays

The example code like here.

```
<?php

   $new_room_result = array();
   $rooms = array('single room' , 'delux room' , 'president room' , 'seavie room');

   foreach($rooms as $room){

     $new_room_result[] = $room;
     // the next step - i want to get the index of after last inserment's index.

   }

?>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: a simple `array_count($new_room_result)` would work if your index started from 0 when performed before the assignment by virtue that an empty array with have 0 items and thus the "first index" is also 0, this will fall apart on named or non-sequential indices.

Comment: `foreach($rooms as $key => $room)` you mean this key (`$key`)? or the key of `$new_room_result[]`? its going to be pushed in the end any way

Comment: I don't see any associative arrays in your code; they're all numerically indexed starting from key 0 and contiguous, so `count($new_room_result)` is the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 foreach($rooms as $room){

   $new_room_result[] = $room;
  end($new_room_result);         // move the internal pointer to the end of the array
  $key = key($new_room_result);
      var_dump($key);

 }
```

Comment: This is redundant; before insertion the index of the next element is `count($new_room_result)` and after insertion the index of the previous element is `count($new_room_result) - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

I have find it out by array_keys() and array_pop() functions.
Whether there is a more easy way to reach what i want.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to get the length of the array:

```
$index = count($new_room_result);
```

after inserting, into $new_room_result its content will be

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'single room' (length=11)
  1 => string 'delux room' (length=10)
  2 => string 'president room' (length=14)
  3 => string 'seavie room' (length=11)
```

Last index is 3, and the index after is 4 which is the size of the array